# How to Override Construct function of Magento without violating "

Tags: magento2, overrides, construct

I created a class with the construction:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {

        parent::__construct($data);
        $this->storeManager       = $storeManager;
    }
```

**But it get the warning:**

> Only dependency assignment operations are allowed in constructor.
>   (using PHPCS)

Is there anyway I can rewrite construct function, still call the parent construct and do not get that warning.
(It happen with ALL construct rewriting functions, and only happened lately, the warning is kinda new).

Answer (score 2):

> 2.3. Class constructor can have only dependency assignment operations and/or argument validation operations. No other operations are allowed.

[source](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/coding-standards/technical-guidelines/technical-guidelines.html#class-design)

You should not assign empty array as predefined value

UPD: Magento core uses `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)` flag to bypass such warning